# Staking reward split between staker and validator

Tags: staking

How does protocol distributes rewards? Does it know the validators fee and sends the % to the validator and other part to staking wallet, or stakers have to send their fees to validator separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a staker you do not have anything to do, the runtime will split the rewards between the validators and your delegated staking account.

The runtime reads the validator commission % and split rewards accordingly.